# One of my pages moves everything else left

Tags: css

I have one page on my website where everything (header, footer, sidebar) moves a little to the left, it only does this on that one page. You can check out what I mean here [beta.crazyblock.com](http://beta.crazyblock.com). The problem is with the page "Games".

The problem is with the scroll bar shifting everything left, but I don't know how to fix this. My site's CSS: http://beta.crazyblock.com/default.css

Comment: Use the snippet to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be caused by the generation of a scroll bar when you load the "games" page - which has more content - this shifts the layout to accomodate the scrollbar.
For example if you reduce the size of the browser small enough so that the "Home" page itself generates the scroll bar, you can then flip between the 2 pages without the movement.

in regards to how you could fix it, there is a solution proposed here:
[Fixed width content irrespective of scrollbar present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108319/fixed-width-content-irrespective-of-scrollbar-present)

Comment: It appears that you're correct. Do you know how I could fix that? Here's my site's CSS: http://beta.crazyblock.com/default.css

Comment: _“Do you know how I could fix that?”_ – https://www.google.com/search?q=fix+scrollbar+shift

Comment: its a bit hacky, but a quick and dirty solution would be to add the property `body { overflow: scroll }` to your CSS. This would force your body element to always show a scroll bar.  otherwise google as suggested for different options that may work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a  tag which is shifting the page. I believe it is here, where the home page reads:

```
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page Content" --><div class="post">
```

and the games page has:

```
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page Content" -->
```

Without the div. Try tracking your opening/closing div tags and make sure they're acting as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the page shifting (Caused by scrollbar) by adding this:

```
html 
{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```